# NUT + CyberPower data stale

Tags: ups

I've got upsmon (nut-client) and upsd (nut-server) set up and almost fully working on an RPi3.

Connected is a CP1500PFCLCD UPS via USB.  `upsd` and `upsmon` start up perfectly every time.  However, given about 2-20 hours of uptime, a "data stale" error will creep in.  The specific error is:

`raspberrypi upsd[14612]: Data for UPS [cyberpower] is stale - check driver`

Followed by many, many more errors resulting from that one, specifically:

`raspberrypi upsmon[9318]: Poll UPS [cyberpower@localhost] failed - Data stale`

Unlike some others, mine does not appear to reconnect on its own.

If I restart the `nut-server` service, then the ~2-20 hour cycle repeats.  How do I "check driver" as it suggests?  I need to get rid of that error, as it is causing other processes to fail.

I run "usb-devices" and the CP1500PFCLCD does show up in the list

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found this fix on another site, working so far for me.

> It turns out that many CyberPower products reset the USB interface if
>   a driver has not connected for 20s.
>
> After some more fiddling I noticed that NUT was set to consider an UPS
>   “stale” (e.g.: “Hey Mr. UPS, you haven’t spoke to me for a while. You
>   know what? I’ll just silently assume that you’re dead and not tell
>   anyone about that.”) after 15 seconds by default.
>
> In order to get a CyberPower USB UPS to stay connected for more than a
>   couple of minutes, you have to change the staleness settings in NUT to
>   give them some headroom and the polling interval in the definition of
>   the UPS itself.

https://nmaggioni.xyz/2017/03/14/NUT-CyberPower-UPS/

Specifically, you need to add a `pollinterval = 15` line to your UPS definition in `/etc/nut/ups.conf` (below your `[my-ups-name]` line), and the two lines `DEADTIME 25` and `MAXAGE 25` to `/etc/nut/upsmon.conf`.

For example:

**/etc/nut/ups.conf:**

```
[cyber1]
        driver = "usbhid-ups"
        port = "auto"
        desc = "CyberPower CP900EPFCLCD"
        pollinterval = 15
```

**/etc/nut/upsmon.conf:**

```
DEADTIME 25
MAXAGE 25
```

*(These config options taken directly from the above-linked page.)*

Note: MAXAGE appears to be deprecated on the newest versions of nut so it may not be applicable to your config.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be preferable if you included the important bits from the answer in case their website goes down.

Comment: Better late than never.... but it appears that `MAXAGE` belongs in `upsd.conf` not `upsmon.conf`. This may be why it appears to be deprecated.

Comment: The linked site also mentions that the `pollinterval` might not be needed, which makes sense - the default is `2`, which is more often, it makes no sense to make it longer.

So the `DEADTIME` is the important part. `MAXAGE` doesn't exist in newer NUT versions.

Comment: Indeed `pollinterval` does not need to be changed and `MAXAGE` is in upsd.conf. Also, nut sucks.

Comment: I don't see any indication of MAXAGE being deprecated. It's still documented in https://networkupstools.org/docs/man/upsd.conf.html . The DEADTIME directive, however, is not.

Answer (score 2):

pollinterval defaults to 30 for the usbhid-ups driver in Debian buster, per the man page.  30 is also the default value in the [current Github source](https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/blob/master/drivers/usbhid-ups.h).

With pollinterval at 15 in ups.conf and DEADTIME at 30 in upsmon.conf on buster, no "stale data" messages have been logged in three days of continuous runtime with a Cyberpower SL750U.  With the default values of pollinterval and DEADTIME, "stale data" messages appeared after ~30 hours of runtime.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: There were earlier comments that pollinterval defaults to 2s and that setting it to 15s might not be necessary.  I was clarifying that the default is 30s on Github and in Debian.  For those versions it needs to be reduced for the Cyberpower UPS.

Comment: This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. Your answer does not provide any new solution to the question. When you get sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I restart driver

```
sudo upsdrvctl start
```

You can do it in Cron

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Home Assistant on a Raspberry Pi4 using HAOS with the NUT Add-on and Integrations. For months I've been struggling with this issue. I happen to have a Tripplite SMART1500LCDT UPS. I've tried about every combination of pollinterval, deadtime, and maxage that I found on other threads. I even upgraded the Pi's firmware to the latest version. None of these suggestions seem to help for very long.

Now I tried setting `pollonly = "enabled"` and it appears to be working without disconnection (48 hours +).

Thanks to **eyal0** at https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/issues/1029 for the tip.

Comment: I used `pollonly = "enabled"` with a CyberPower 650VA 8 outlet UPS and this resolved the disconnect issue. Thanks!